# How to identify the specific hour of the day in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

I am writing a plugin which will send text messages to a clients list but they are on shared hosting with send email limitations by the hour. I need to be able to identify the specific hour of the day when another email is send from the server do I can set up a sent email track log.

I pretty much have the rest of the programming figured out but I do not know how to identify the start of each hour in the day so I can set up the tracking.

Comment: "identify the specific hour of the day when another email is send from the server"  You might want to rephrase that. It's not really clear what you're asking. Do you want the hour of the current time? The hour of a given timestamp?

Comment: Thank you for responding... what i am actually looking for is the timestamp for the start of each our in the given day... for example if an email is sent at 7:10am how can I identify the time stamp of 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have hours passed today use this:

```
$currentHoursOfToday=date("H");
echo $currentHoursOfToday;
```

To save a date using this exact hour use this:

```
$today=new DateTime("now");
$today->setTime($currentHoursOfToday, 0);
echo $today->format("Y-m-d H\h");
```

Comment: Thanks so much... as i was typing my response to patrick date("H") popped in my head and you confirmed it... got to love this site thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, just posted it even tho i was not sure if it is what you mean. As others already said it was not clear what you are asking.

Comment: lol... yeah sometimes its hard to get this old brain to convey enven simple things... thanks again

Answer (score 2):

[`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime) might be what you're looking for.